# Magnetic Field Flux Density Disambiguation

Tags: electromagnetism

The Electric Field is defined as the electric force exerted on a positive test particle:

$$\vec{E}=\frac{\vec{F}}{q}$$

The Electric Flux is defined as:

$$\Phi=\iint \vec{E}\cdot \vec{dS}$$

The Electric Flux Density is defined as:

$$\vec{D}=\epsilon_{0} \vec{E}$$

The Magnetic Field $B$ is defined as the magnetic force exerted on a moving test particle and is also called the Magnetic Flux Density.

The Magnetic Flux Density is defined as:

$$\Phi=\iint \vec{B}\cdot \vec{dS}$$

The Mangetic Field Strength is defined as:

$$\vec{H}=\frac{\vec{B}}{\mu_{0}}$$

From what I see there is a direct correlation between $E$ and $B$ but not between $D$ and $H$ which is confusing:

$$\iint \vec{E}\cdot \vec{dS} \leftrightarrow \iint \vec{B}\cdot \vec{dS}$$

$$\iint \vec{E}\cdot \vec{dS}=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_{0}}\leftrightarrow \iint \vec{B}\cdot \vec{dS}=\mu_{0}I$$

$$\vec{D}=\epsilon_{0} \vec{E} \leftrightarrow \vec{B}=\mu_{0} \vec{H}$$

To my knowledge $B$ in the Magnetic Field is the analog of $E$ in the Electric Field and $H$ of $D$, but from what I see now it seems that $B$ is the analog of $D$ and $H$ of $E$ which to me doesn't make sense. So how can $B$ called the Flux Density when according to the equations $H$ should be called that?